# CSS :where() selector not usable in Electron app

Tags: css, electron, microsoft-teams

I am currently trying to embed a website into the MS Teams desktop app. As far as I know this is an Electron app. The integration works fine but the styles are broken. From what I have discovered so far, it seems that the CSS `:where()` selector is not working.

Is there any information about known problems in this direction? Are workarounds or polyfills for this issue available?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find information about this problem, but according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where), here is a workaround :

```css
/* Selects any paragraph inside a header, main
   or footer element that is being hovered */
:where(header, main, footer) p:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The above is equivalent to the following */
header p:hover,
main p:hover,
footer p:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Not really equivalent no. The difference is in the specificity of the two versions. Thats why we would like to keep the :where() version. But sure, if there is no other way, then we need to rewrite the CSS. Just wondering if there is another way and why it is not working in the first place since Electron uses chromium as rendering engine (which should support it)

Comment: @Fynn `:where()` is supported on chrome [since version 88](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_where). According to the [electron-to-chromium package](https://npm.runkit.com/electron-to-chromium), electron 11 depended on chromium 87. I couldn't find which version of electron is used for Microsoft Teams desktop app because developer tools are not enabled. I don't think Microsoft used Electron 11 or a prior version but it could explain why `:where()` does not work.

Comment: Currently Microsoft Teams uses Electron version 10.4.  Please take a look at [Access DevTools on the desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools).